# How to make 3 view controllers in storyboard and embed in one PageViewController？

Tags: ios, swift

[image: code]
Here is my code.

But it didn't work.

[image: storyboard]

and this is my storyboard.

I want to let these 3 views embed in one view and then that view can explore these 3 views one by one by sliding

Answer (score 0):

One error that I see is that you are missing a data source in. Your `viewDidLoad` add `dataSource = self` `delegate = self`

Let me know if that solves it.